# Formatting string right in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I need help with my string. I have a string for example `45,4512°`. How can I format it to `45,4°` in xaml or with a `ValueConverter`? The value is bound to a `TextBlock`.

Comment: how are you getting `45.1` from `45.4512`?

Comment: sorry i mean 45,4° and than rounded.

Comment: You can modify get accessor of related property in your viewmodel class: `public double MyProp { get { return Math.Round(myProp,2); }; set {myProp = value;}}` It will be easier if you are going to round in all windows in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't do this in your xaml, while there are ways of doing it this way like using converters it is simpler to adjust the property you are binding to on your view model, or create a new property to bind the decimal to by using the following code:

```
var convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal("45,4512")
convertDecimal = Math.Round(convertDecimal , 1);
```